# Is there a way to tap Brokers Hideout for mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urborg%2C%20Tomb%20of%20Yawgmoth) in play can I tap a [Brokers Hideout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brokers%20Hideout) for one black mana before it gets sacrificed?

Comment: If your aim is just what is in the title of the question, there are many ways to do it, including good old [Blood Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83008).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brokers Hideout is a triggered ability that goes on the stack. All players can react on that, and Brokers Hideout is a land on the battlefield at that moment, so with Urborg in play you can certainly get another mana out of it.